# cloud-init fetch script from secure host

Tags: cloud-init

It's useful how you can place a script on a host somewhere and just use the following to use it as your cloud-init:

```
#include example.com/my-script
```

But if the script contains sensitive information or other stuff you don't want on a publicly-accessible host, is there a directive you can use to load a script from a secure host?